# How to merge values in columnB based on values in columnA

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a xlsx looks like this:

```
Company    N
A          1234;878;3434
A          5678;873
B          539
B          00;123
C          155;741;655
C          5377;454
```

I'm using pandas to import it into my program, can I merge N based on their company?

Desired outcome: `{'A': [1234,878,3434,5678,873], 'B': [539, 00, 123], 'C': [155, 741, 655, 5377, 454]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groupby and split, then apply list and turn to dict like:

```
import itertools
(df.groupby('Company').apply(lambda x: 
 list(map(int,itertools.chain.from_iterable(x['N'].str.split(';'))))).to_dict())
```

---

```
{'A': [1234, 878, 3434, 5678, 873],
 'B': [539, 0, 123],
 'C': [155, 741, 655, 5377, 454]}
```

you can also use sum, for concating the lists, but not recommended for large data(it has performance issues, better use itertools)

**EDIT** for slicing 2 elements from the list use:

```
import itertools
(df.groupby('Company').apply(lambda x: 
 list(map(int,[k[:2] for k in itertools.chain.from_iterable(x['N'].str.split(';'))]))).to_dict())
```

this outputs:

```
{'A': [12, 87, 34, 56, 87], 'B': [53, 0, 12], 'C': [15, 74, 65, 53, 45]}
```

*Note the use of `map()` here, it is used to convert the list elements from string to a int. Since the original dtype is a string and we do a `str.split()`, the list has strings.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your great solution! Can you explain the map() part please? Also, how do I slice it if I only want to keep the first 2 digits? Ex. 'A': [12, 87, 34, 56, 87], 'B': [53, 0, 12], 'C': [15, 74, 65, 53, 45]?

Comment: @Alex check updated answer under EDIT. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: It helps! Thank you so much! So if I don't need to convert string to int, I don't need to use map() and list() since it's already a list?

Comment: @Alex yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient with me! Hope you have a blessed day!

Comment: @Alex you too. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can read the xlsx file and convert your dataframe into a dictionary using the below code

```
import pandas as pd
xls_dict = xls_data.to_dict('records')
print(xls_dict)
```

Then, you can generate your required output with the below code

```
output_dict = dict()

for xls_dat in xls_dict:
    key_list = list()
    if 'N' in xls_dat:
        if xls_dat.get('Company') in output_dict:
            lis = output_dict.get(xls_dat.get('Company'))
            lis2 = [int(i) for i in xls_dat.get('N').split(';')]
            output_dict[xls_dat.get('Company')] = lis + lis2
        else:
            key_list = [int(i) for i in xls_dat.get('N').split(';')]
            output_dict[xls_dat.get('Company')] = key_list
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': [1234, 878, 3434, 5678, 873], 'B': [539, 0, 123], 'C': [155, 741, 655, 5377, 454]}
```